# IO c# Методы ReadByte() WriteByte() FileStream

Tags: c#, filestream

Привет, друзья.

Подскажите мне пожалуйста по такому вопросу

Вот есть класс БАЙТОВОГО потока `FileStream`. У него имеются соответственно методы для чтения и для записи единичного байта `ReadByte()`, `WriteByte()`.

Отсюда у меня два вопроса

1. Если например текстовый документ содержит такой символ, который при преобразовании из char в byte не вмещается в один байт, тогда каким образом он раскладывает этот символ ??
2. Почему в данном коде

   ```
   static void Main()
   {
       int x = 0;
       FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\3.djvu", FileMode.Open);
       FileStream copy = new FileStream(@"D:\32.djvu", FileMode.CreateNew);
       do
       {
           if (x != -1) { x = fs.ReadByte(); copy.WriteByte((byte)x); } else return;
       } while (true);
       fs.Close();
       copy.Close();
   }
   ```

В этом выражении `copy.WriteByte((byte)x);` на выходе создается файл с набором символов, а не набором цифр. Ведь `FileStream` это байтовый поток и на выходе файл должен был преобразовать все символы из исходного файла в цифры и записать их на диск ??

Comment: >В этом выражении copy.WriteByte((byte)x); на выходе создается файл с набором символов, а не набором цифр

о каких символах идет речь? С чего вы взяли, что именно символы, а не двоичные данные?

Comment: Если открыть через редактор этот файл который получился на выходе, то там символьная краказябра

Comment: > преобразовании из char в byte не вмещается в один байт

От кодировки много чего зависит. Не обязательно что один байт - один символ. Например, кодировка utf-8 это кодировка переменной длинны. Это значит, что размер любого символа закодированного с помощью этой кодировки, может достигать от одного до 4 байт.

Comment: >Если открыть через редактор этот файл который получился на выходе, то там символьная краказябра

а вы попробуйте какую-нибудь dll открыть  через-какаой-нибудь текстовый редактор. Возможно даже, что у вас это получится. И на выходе вы также получите беспорядочный  набор символов. Однако это совсем не означает, что dll состоит из символов. 
То, что вы не можете открыть полученный файл, всего лишь означает, что вы его неверно скопировали, а не то, что двоичный файл "состоит из символов". Никаких "символов" в разумеется нем нет - в документации говорится, что WriteByte пишет байты, а не символы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. То, что у текстового документа есть *формат* (то есть, то, что из одного или нескольких *байт* могут складываться *символы*), классу `FileStream` безразлично. В любом случае файл, будь он текстовый или нет, состоит из байт, и данный класс читает его побайтно, а не посимвольно. Это значит, что считанный байт на самом деле может вполне быть «половинкой» или даже «одной шестой» какого-нибудь многобайтного символа.
2. По той же причине. Процедуры, читающие файл, получают не один символ за раз, а один байт. Если символ большой и помещается в несколько байт, эти байты читаются и обрабатываются по одному.

Кстати, ваша процедура копирования неверна. Вы зачем-то пишете в выходной файл лишний байт, и не закрываете файлы (из-за раннего return'а), что чревато потерей данных. Надо так:

```
static void Main()
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\3.djvu", FileMode.Open))
    using (FileStream copy = new FileStream(@"D:\32.djvu", FileMode.CreateNew))
    {
        int val;
        while ((val = fs.ReadByte()) >= 0)
            copy.WriteByte((byte)val);
    }
}
```

Но это для учёбы. На практике пользуйтесь просто

```
File.Copy(@"D:\3.djvu", @"D:\32.djvu");
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь и совет

Comment: @polyakov_s: Пожалуйста!